# Get Linux Server Hardware Information from Windows Web service

Tags: linux, windows, web, server, hardware

Firstly, I apologize for my bad English.

My purpose,I need get a some information from my Linux server.Example : Get CPU,RAM or CPU temperature.I know those commands on Linux Terminal Commands.
(free -m,df -lh).But I need connect on my Windows PC and open Chrome then go on "www.GETMYSERVERINFO.com" then i wanna see my server hardware information.How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend [firehol/netdata](https://github.com/firehol/netdata/).

Check this [demo](http://london.my-netdata.io/default.html#system_network).